# Centering 100% width <ul>

Tags: html, css

Lately i've have made navigation buttons that would toggle dropdown menu when clicked, Unfortunately i have made them with `px` units and by that consequence the menu would would stay left when enlarged to `2000px` width, since i have done it to fit in center for `1200px` width only.

I also think i have made it pretty hardcoded and very difficult to look into so i'l explain important parts.

---

## Explanation:

So at first, i didn't start menu with `div` container, i started it straightly with `ul`:

`<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">`

Then inside this `ul` i have made `<div class="dropdown">` container, which includes 3 elements:

```
<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" value="drop" id="drop-1" class="dropper">
        <li><label class="down-nav" id="down-nav-1" for="drop-1" style="text-decoration:none">Knives <b class="caret"> &#9660;</b></label></li>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="m9_bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M9 Bayonet</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="karambit" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:59px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Karambit</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:116px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bayonet</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="butterfly" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:170px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Butterfly Knife</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="flip" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:225px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Flip Knife</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="falchion" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:280px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Falchion Knife</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="gut" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:334.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Gut Knife</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="shadow" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:390px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Shadow Daggers</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="huntsman" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:444px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Huntsman Knife</a>
            <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="bowie" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:498.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bowie Knife</a>                    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also note that `Text1` class was just for testing, I don't use it.

So this was the result of css and html for single navigation:

```css
.down-bar {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 39px;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  background-color: black;
  height: 55px;
  min-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 12.5%;
}
.down-nav {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 105%;
  top: 17px;
  left: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.down-nav:hover {
  color: white;
  border: solid 3px gray;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.down-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.caret {
  font-size: 20%;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0em;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
  margin-top: 53.4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 200px;
  width: 164px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 8% 0px 15% 0%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 0%;
  text-indent: 4%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
.dropper {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#drop-1:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
#drop-1:checked ~ li #down-nav-1 {
  border: solid 3px gray;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="down-bar" style="list-style:hidden">
 <div class="dropdown">
  <input type="checkbox" value="drop" id="drop-1" class="dropper">
  <li><label class="down-nav" id="down-nav-1" for="drop-1" style="text-decoration:none">Knives <b class="caret"> &#9660;</b></label></li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="m9_bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>M9 Bayonet</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="karambit" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:59px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Karambit</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="bayonet" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:116px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bayonet</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="butterfly" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:170px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Butterfly Knife</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="flip" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:225px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Flip Knife</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="falchion" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:280px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Falchion Knife</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="gut" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:334.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Gut Knife</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="shadow" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:390px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Shadow Daggers</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="huntsman" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:444px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Huntsman Knife</a>
   <a href="#" class="Text1"><label class="bowie" style="width:30px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:498.5px;cursor:pointer;"></label>Bowie Knife</a>     
  </div>
 </div>
```

## Code:

All 7 navigation buttons are made the same, you can see full website [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qxaxjtku/1/embedded/result/) ( Please try scaling down and up, also please make sure i changed some things for jsfiddle compability, `display: webkit-flex` was not necessary there. ).

## Problem:

What can i do to center my navigation? is there any better way doing something simillar? Thanks! ( [Full Code](https://jsfiddle.net/qxaxjtku/1/) )

Comment: You can try to set `text-align: center;` for your `<ul>`, and `display: inline-block;` for your `<li>`

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid**, fix that first. The **only** direct child element that a `ul` can have is  `li`.

Comment: @connexo I'm sorry i couldn't understand, what do i need to change exactly?

Comment: What I wrote. You cannot have *any other direct child elements* in a `ul` than `li`. Any non-`li` element **must** be wrapped in a `li`.

Comment: @connexo So i must wrap `div` in `li`?